# Google Storage Share Public link doesn't work

Tags: google-cloud-storage

It used to work in my Chrome, but now I don't see the check boxes.

Am I the only one that doesn't see the check boxes next to public link?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BOQA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are using an account that is not the owner of those objects. The "Public link" link will appear whenever the object is publicly accessible, but the checkbox should only appear if you have permission to change whether the object is publicly accessible. Please make sure you're viewing the objects with an account that owns those objects.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm logged in with the same user used to create the bucket, but I cannot see the checkbox. I've posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51727800/google-storage-public-link-checkbox-disappeared