# Google Storage - Public link checkbox disappeared

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Since a few days ago I was able to get a public link to a file to make it publicly readable in my bucket on Google Storage just by clicking on a checkbox in it's row.

The label of that Checkbox was saying "Public Link".

You can see a screenshot describing what I'm describing:
[Image](http://www.addictionlab.it/addiction_non_cancellare/checkbox.png)

But, since few days ago, this checkbox has disappeared and to enable a public link for my file I have to go through a window and add permissions for a *fake* user called allUsers as said in [this page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public)

Is there a way to reenable the checkbox?

Is something changed on google storage or have I misconfigured something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [changed on 18th July](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/release-notes#july_18_2018). Objects can no longer be made public through one-click actions.

As you mentioned all possible ways of making an object public are described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).